# default contructor of unordered_map, the bool type will be set as false?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

I have some questions about the default contructor of unordered_map.

Here is the code:

```
unordered_map<int, bool> m;

cout <<boolalpha << m[0] << endl;
```

The output is true or false?

I know the element is constructed using its default constructor, but the mapped value is true or false? Is this undefined behavior?

In vs2013, the output is `false`.

Actually, i want to remove the duplicate elements in an array. I want to solve the problem like this:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4};

unordered_map<int, bool> m;
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)

{
     if (!m[a[i]])
     {     
         a[j++] = a[i];
         m[a[i]] = true;
     }  
}
```

Thanks, i really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`operator []` of `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` inserts a *value-initialized* element if the key doesn't exist (§23.4.4.3 [map.access]/p1, §23.5.4.3 [unord.map.elem]/p2; §8.5 [dcl.init]/p17). For non-class, non-array types, *value-initialization* means *zero-initialization* (§8.5 [dcl.init]/p8). Thus, the `bool` in your example is guaranteed to be `false`.

A (IMO cleaner) way to accomplish what you are trying to do is to use a `std::set` (or `std::unordered_set`):

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4};

std::set<int> s(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), a);
```

After the `std::copy` call, the first `s.size()` elements of `a` are the non-duplicate elements. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecb237a4b7856517).

Or an even cleaner way (hat tip to @Praetorian):

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4};

std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
int * last = std::unique(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
int dedup_size = last - a;
```

The first `dedup_size` elements of `a` are the non-duplicate elements. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67be814f1131f6a2).

Comment: +1 but wouldn't an even cleaner way be to call `sort` and then `unique`?

Comment: @Praetorian True :) I considered both, actually...though you have to calculate the size yourself with `unique` since you can't use `erase` with arrays...

Comment: @T.C. Thank you so much. love you and stackoverflow.^^

Answer (score 2):

For `std::map` and `std::unordered_map`, if the key is not present, a new **value-initialized** element is added to the `std::map`/`std::unordered_map`.

And a type of `bool` is value-initialized as `false`. No undefined behavior.

Comment: so it is not default-initialized?

Comment: @pqnet That's what I recall.

Comment: Confirmed. Deleting my answer as not relevant.

Comment: @Yu Hao really appreciated your answer. love you and stackoverflow.^^